# SQL: How to return count for the prior 4, 13, and 52 weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of IDs (lPeopleID) to which I would like to know the following information on:

- Number of studies completed in the prior 4 weeks, prior 13 weeks, and prior 52 weeks (prior to date: dMailingDate = '5/23/2016') - preferably in separate columns

  How do I include the information above in the query below? How to add in dCompletedDate prior to 4, 13, and 52 weeks for all studies sent out before '5/23/2016'?

```
 select *
 from TStudy
 where dMailingDate <'5/23/2016'
 and lStudyID in (select lStudyID from TAssignments where lStudyTypeID in 
 (0,3,5))
 and lPeopleID in
 (
 *insert lPeopleID here*
 )
```

Note:
dMailingDate = date that study was sent out
dCompletedDate = date that respondent completed study

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  How can a study be completed *before* the mailing date?  I'm confused.  And what does it mean for a *study* to be completed?  You seem to have data at the *respondent* level.

Comment: So break your goal into achievable pieces. You said "completed" is based on dCompletedDate yet the query you posted refers to dMailingDate. Why? But let's ignore that. Define PRECISELY what "prior 4 weeks" is based on the current date (or whichever date you intend to use as a basis for this calculation). Repeat that process for your other periods. Until you do that, there is little point to attempting anything else. And clarify - you want studies completed per person in your list?

Comment: I included dMailingDate in there because I JUST want to look at survey completion to surveys that were only mailed out before 5/23/2016. I didn't include CompletedDate yet because not sure how to include: Number of studies completed in the prior 4 weeks, prior 13 weeks, and prior 52 weeks in the best way visually (preferably in 3 seperate columns)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much confidence in my answer because the question is somewhat vague. If this is off the mark perhaps it will spark an idea for you.

```
DECLARE @dBaseMailingDate DATETIME;

SET @dBaseMailingDate = '05/23/2016';

SELECT    ts.*
        , Minus4.[Number of Studies Minus 4 Weeks]
        , Minus13.[Number of Studies Minus 13 Weeks]
        , Minus52.[Number of Studies Minus 52 Weeks]
FROM      TStudy AS ts
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT   ts1.lStudyID
                     , COUNT(*) AS [Number of Studies Minus 4 Weeks]
              FROM     TStudy AS ts1
              WHERE    ts1.dCompletedDate < DATEADD(WEEK, -4, @dBaseMailingDate)
                       AND ts1.lPeopleID IN (ts.lPeopleID)
              GROUP BY ts1.lStudyID
          )      AS Minus4 ON ts.lStudyId = Minus4.lStudyID
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT   ts2.lStudyID
                     , COUNT(*) AS [Number of Studies Minus 13 Weeks]
              FROM     TStudy AS ts2
              WHERE    ts2.dCompletedDate < DATEADD(WEEK, -13, @dBaseMailingDate)
                       AND ts2.lPeopleID IN (ts.lPeopleID)
              GROUP BY ts2.lStudyID
          )      AS Minus13 ON ts.lStudyId = Minus13.lStudyID
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT   ts3.lStudyID
                     , COUNT(*) AS [Number of Studies Minus 52 Weeks]
              FROM     TStudy AS ts3
              WHERE    ts3.dCompletedDate < DATEADD(WEEK, -52, @dBaseMailingDate)
                       AND ts3.lPeopleID IN (ts.lPeopleID)
              GROUP BY ts3.lStudyID
          )      AS Minus52 ON ts.lStudyId = Minus52.lStudyID
WHERE     ts.dMailingDate < @dBaseMailingDate
          AND ts.lStudyID IN (
                                 SELECT ta.lStudyID
                                 FROM   TAssignments AS ta
                                 WHERE  ta.lStudyTypeID IN (0, 3, 5)
                             )
          AND ts.lPeopleID IN (1);
```

Comment: It's telling me that it's invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the missing GROUP BY clauses. This is why everyone always asks for sample data. Without it we have no way to check our answer before posting it. You could query a limited set of rows from your tables, export them to CSV, and then use a tool like this (http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) to convert that CSV output to table create and insert statement we can use.